# accessing values from php array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, for-loop

I have been having an issue getting values out of an array that is formatted like so:

```
array(
   [key]=>array(
            [0]=>value
            [1]=>value
            [2]=>value)
   [key]=>array(
            [0]=>value
            [1]=>value))
```

I am using a queue to run through each key as the queue item and process the information. so to create the queue item I have tried this:

```
while ($array = $result->fetchAssoc())
                {

                    $queue->createItem($array);

                }
```

this fails to create any items so I have used this method instead

```
if ($array != 0 || $array != NULL) {
       foreach ($array as $row) { 
            $queue->createItem($row);
       }
}
```

Once the queue item is created the queue calls a function passing the queue $item and here is where I have problems as I can successfully get all the values of the second level array but I can not access the Key of the first level.

```
function work_function($item){

   foreach($item as $row=>$job){
       //do something
   }
}
```

In my function I have tried:

```
 //1
    $arrayKEY= $item;

    //2
    foreach($item as $row){
     $arrayKEY= $row;
    }
```

I just cannot get the values I need. What am I doing wrong/can I do to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29

Comment: @user975044. Any chance of the less prissy definition of $queue? Specifically which Php object is it?

Comment: Ok, specifically for my case i am using: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7  terrible doc though.. Drupal i know.. but that shouldn't matter to the problem. A queue is basically a way of loading objects into a container or line to be processed. So if I want the number 1,2,3,4 to be processed in that order through the same function I can create a queue object for each number. so in the queue I have 4 objects which contain the numbers 1,2,3,4 in that order.

Comment: To start processing the queue the first object, which is number 1, gets pulled from the queue and processed. I shouldn't haven mentioned this as it really isn't causing the issue here. It is being able to access the array key and values in a function

Comment: @user975044: We all know what a queue is, we're asking you what your `$queue` object is, specifically.

Comment: I think I'm missing the problem here.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: getting the values of the array in the function work_function() I can't seem to get the key and values

Comment: @user975044: Does the `foreach` you have work getting the 1st level of elements (ie. does `var_dump($job)` print anything)?

Answer (score 1):

There's not much info here, but if the array is like you show, it's a multi-dimensional array, and thus needs 2 for loops.

```
function work_function($item){
   foreach($item as $row=>$job){
       echo "Row $row:\n";
       foreach($job as $value){
          echo $value."\n";
       }
   }
}
```